# how To Use wp_link_pages With bootstrap 4 for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

Respectable Gurus
I am using Wordpress and composing Custom Theme styling with bootstrap V 4.3.1, I am stuck at the stage of Pages Pagination (wp_link_pages();  in wordpress), I am not able to style the pagination as desired, I am not as much guru at wordpress and specially in styling things.
Desired Styling of Pagination is attached in screenshot. Please HELP...!
I Want to style the pagination like this bellow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function isvek_pagination_page( $output, string $args = '' ) {
       global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;

       $args = [
           'before'         => '<nav class="mt-4" aria-label="Навигация страниц" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation"><ul class="pagination justify-content-center m-0">',
           'after'          => "</ul></nav>",
           'current_before' => '<li class="page-item active"><span itemprop="name" class="page-link">',
           'current_after'  => '</span></li>',
           'pagelink'       => '%',
           'link_before'    => '<li class="page-item">',
           'link_after'     => '</li>',
       ];

       $args = (object) apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $args );

       if ( ! $multipage ) {
           return;
       }

       $output = $args->before;

       for ( $i = 1; $i < $numpages + 1; $i ++ ) {
           $j      = str_replace( '%', $i, $args->pagelink );
           $output .= '';

           if ( $i !== $page || ! $more && 1 === $page ) {
               $link   = str_replace( 'post-page-numbers', 'page-numbers page-link', _wp_link_page( $i ) );
               $link   = str_replace( '<a', '<a itemprop="url"', $link );
               $output .= sprintf(
                   '%1$s%2$s%3$s</a>%4$s',
                   $args->link_before,
                   $link,
                   $j,
                   $args->link_after
               );
           } else {
               $output .= sprintf(
                   '%1$s%2$s%3$s',
                   $args->current_before,
                   $j,
                   $args->current_after
               );
           }
       }

       $output .= $args->after;

       return $output;
   }

   add_filter( 'wp_link_pages', 'isvek_pagination_page' );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?